# how to replace global variable in a recursive function

Tags: python-3.x

Here, I written some codes to find components numbers of a graph, the input style is like this:

```
5
4
0 1
0 2
1 2
3 4
```

First line is the number of vertices, second line is the number of edges, the rest shows each edges.

In my codes, I used a global variable in the recursive function, so is there some good ways to replace it? In other way, how to program the function in a better way?

Code:

```
def dfs(graph, root_vertex):
    global visited

    visited.add(root_vertex)

    for pairs in graph:
        if (root_vertex  in pairs) and pairs[1 -pairs.index(root_vertex)] not in visited :
            visited.add(pairs[1 - pairs.index(root_vertex)])
            dfs(graph, pairs[1 - pairs.index(root_vertex)])  


vertex_num = int(input())
edge_num = int(input())
graph = []

for i in range(edge_num):
    graph.append(tuple(sorted(map(int,input().split()))))


tot_vertex = set([i for i in range(vertex_num)])

visited = set()
count  = 0


while list(tot_vertex -  visited):
    dfs(graph, list(set(tot_vertex) -  set(visited))[0])
    count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: The problem may not stated clearly, more information please visit https://uchicago.kattis.com/problems/uchicagoplacement.connected

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Your code runs fine for me. Should it do something that it is not currently doing? Please further explain where the problem is. If the problem is you do not want to use the global variable, you don't need to use `global` -- you can delete `global visited` and move the line `visited = set()` before the `dfs` function and the code should still work the same.

Comment: Thank you. I know this code works well. What I want is just remove global variable, and you have answered me! I will try to understand why. Thank you!

Comment: The reason for *why* is that the keyword `global` is used when there are more than one variable with the same name, one variable in the local scope of the function, and another variable of the same name in the global scope. Since you only have *one* variable named `visited` you do not need to use global. Hope that helps you!

Comment: Can you explain more about the recursive function? Where exactly should I put visited = set() ? I think I am really  confused with outputs of recursive functions, can you help me to understand?

Comment: Sure. You already have `visited = set()` below the `dfs` function (before `count = 0`). Just move that line `visited = set()` up as the first line of code, above the `dfs` function. And delete the first line in the function `global visited` <-- remove that line, you don't it

Comment: Amazing! But why? should the visited is called just in the while loop? why  placing the visited = set() at the first line can make it?

Comment: Because you only have one variable named `visited`, so you don't need to use `global`, but if you had other variable also named visited, then you would use `global` to tell python which variable you want to use.

Comment: oh, I see! Thank you very much! It helps me a lot!

Comment: Sure, It confused me before also, so I'm very happy to help you too!

Answer (score 0):

When you need variables accessible across different function invocations - whether different functions or recursive invocations of the same function - the pattern is to make the function(s) methods of a class, then use a member variable for the "global". This is a fundamental use case of classes.

Here the `visited` set can be a member variable as long as you'll never search from more than one thread at a time.  That's okay as a restriction because the `Search` should be the class, not the thing being searched. If you need to search with more than one thread simultaneously, then create one `Search` object per thread.